# how do I create a factory that uses http.get and passes it to multiple controllers in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs app that is getting more complex so I need to break out thing into more than one controller. I need to create a factory to fetch my data using http.get and share that data between a couple of controllers. I have a simple version passing the data into the controllers but I am not sure about the factory that is using the http.get. Also, I want to make sure the http.get only gets called one time, for working example code see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2vgqMKH2egel4gA0owT)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data2', function($http){
  var getDataUrlString = "myhappyurl.com";

  return $http.get(getDataUrlString);
})

myApp.factory('Data', function(){
  return {message:"cool data from factory"}
})

myApp.controller('firstController', function($scope, Data){
  $scope.firstData = Data;
})

myApp.controller('secondController', function($scope, Data){
  $scope.secondData = Data;
})
```

I think I am very close with the factory that I want to use 'Data2'. The Data factory which just returns the string message works just great as you can see in the example code I provided, I just need help bridging the gap from simple string to the http.get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory Data2 returns a promise, so you need to do access the response once the promise is resolved/rejected:-

```
 myApp.controller('firstController', function($scope, Data2){

   Data2.then(function(response){
        $scope.firstData = response.data;
   }).catch(function(error){
      //handle error
   });
 });
```

Note that, since you are returning promise as the factory instance and factories are singletons this wont be instantiated everytime, means you will always get the same promise and the url will not be called again and again. You may instead want to wrap it inside a function and return an object from the factory with a key with the function reference.